# JavaScript: form on every image in an image slider?

Tags: javascript, forms, image, slider

Here is what I have as an image slider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-->
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "/image0.jpeg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "/image1.jpeg"
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src = "/image2.jpeg"
    //-->
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="/research/logos/.jpeg" name="slide" width="400" height="400">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var step = 1

    function slideit() {
      document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
      if (step < 3)
        step++
        else
          step = 1
      setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
    }
    slideit()
    //-->
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to put a form on top of an image from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_form_on_image.asp. A simple form where there is one button through which the viewer could send responses to would suffice.

Could anyone kindly shed light on how to combine the two? Thanks!

Comment: What form ? input? select? button?

Comment: @zer00ne, a simple form with one button to send responses to would be suffice. I added this to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: ...? ok...what or where is this *"original question"?* Or is this form actually the slider and what you want to ask is: "how to create a background image slider?"

Comment: oh...@zer00ne, my question is simply how to incorporate a form onto every image of the slider shown above?... Let me know where it's unclear...